# How I can print results from a Java program in a HTML file?

Tags: view, printf, put, verify, presentation

I have a Java program that checks how many emails are unverified/unread in INBOX, Junk Email, Drafts, Sent Items and Deleted Items.
How can I print these results in an HTML file as a presentation with related explanations?
Thanks for help.

To received information and steps needed to be done to achieve the expected results.